# Objective C - Tap Gesture counting

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, ipad

I have some imageViews on my View, now I want to change the background.color of the image in my imageView. By clicking second time on the same imageView it should change to the first image.

How I can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Keep a BOOL or enum ivar to keep track of the image state. When reacting to the tap, exchange the image.

You could have a custom subclass of image view to keep this state always associated with the right object.

```
// .h
typedef enum { StateOriginal, StateFlipped } FlipState;

@interface FlippableImageView : UIImageView
@property (nonatomic, assign) FlipState state;
@end

// in view controller
if (flipImageView.state == StateOriginal) {
  flipImageView.image = imageFlipped;
  flipImageView.state = StateFlipped;
}
else { 
  flipImageView.image = imageOriginal;
  flipImageView.state = StateOriginal;
}
```

The class could also hold both images and run a nice animation...

Comment: the problem I have is, I don't know which image was clicked because they aren't defined in the .h file. They were dynamically generated by parsing from a XML file.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Variable to check how many times your ImageView has been touched.
This can be changed in :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if (touch.view == imageView) {
        // Make that variable ++;
        if (variable == 2){
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];
        }
    }
}
```